# "Listen to your songs on your music collection" or "listen to songs on your music collection"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I am not sure where to put the word "your" and if you should put it twice.

> I want to listen to your songs on your music collection.
>
> I want to listen to songs on your music collection.

I am not sure which one is the best, and if both are grammatical? Any rule on this?

Comment: songs should be *in* your music collection, not on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say

> I want to listen to **the/some** songs **in** your music collection.

You could formulate it in various different ways, but if you can avoid saying the same word twice in a sentence, it is generally better to.

The songs are in **your music collection**, so by inference they are **yours** too, and it does not need to be repeated.

Adding 'the' or 'some' is not required, but seems to flow off the tongue a bit better to me.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, both sentences in your examples are (almost) correct:"**in** your music collection" sounds better.

**"your songs"** can have 2 meanings:

- the songs you own;
- the songs you created, performed, recorded...

**"your music collection"** refers to the entire archive of songs you have (regardless of who was involved in making it).

If you use "your" **twice**, you somehow put a stronger accent on the following meaning:

> You have many songs, but I want to hear the ones where you are the artist.

I also endorse the suggested sentence provided in the answer from **@fred2**: "I want to listen to the/some songs in your music collection."